# Sending and receiving json flask

Tags: python, json, flask, post, video-streaming

I am trying to get live video from a raspberry pi and compress it, put it into a json and after sending to my server. Now I am trying to just send the json without compressing. I have a problem when I am sending. I am trying to post it like this:

```
headers = {'ContentType':'application/json'}
frame = np.random.randint(256, size=res, dtype='uint8')
paylaod_tx = json.dumps({'shape':res, 'frame':json.dumps(frame,cls=NumpyArrayEncoder)}) #each pixel will have a rgb color and the color will be stored into a matrix, each matrix will store a row
request.post('http://192.168.207:500',json=payload,headers=headers)
```

The server side:

```
 while True:
        t = time.time()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(t)
            data1=request.get_json(force=True)
            print(data1)
            payload_rx = json.loads(data1)
            frame1 = np.asarray(
                        json.loads(payload_rx['frame']), 
                        dtype='uint8'
                    ).reshape(payload_rx['shape'])

            cv.imshow('test', frame1)
            if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('d'):        # stop the video is the key 'd' is pressed (you can change as per your choice)
                break
            return 'ok'
```

Is actual printing the json, which is good and is printing the time:

> 1658586054.8141189 {"shape": [5, 5, 3], "frame": "[[[244, 15, 11], [132, 52, 234], [69, 13, 220], [88, 109, 62], [25, 97, 22]], [[143,
> 164, 89], [139, 42, 23], [180, 159, 69], [17, 174, 246], [211, 144,
> 92]], [[71, 140, 61], [40, 234, 236], [75, 46, 97], [10, 214, 62],
> [19, 85, 112]], [[3, 111, 164], [51, 147, 173], [15, 227, 245], [7,
> 252, 230], [2, 60, 128]], [[112, 87, 95], [191, 176, 155], [26, 81,
> 7], [72, 241, 11], [207, 72, 192]]]"}

I recreating the image as you can see in the picture, I am trying to use just a 5 and 5 pixel image to do not overload the internet because is not compress yet. The image is generating
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCJ7T.png)

The problem is: after first json sent the whole process is freez, the client and the server.

The client is giving me this error message between the first and the second json:

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in
> "/home/alex/projectgit/ConvergeCast/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"

I tried to put a previous version of opencv. Was that ok?

Before the server gave me the error 308 I put the and now at least is a connection

```
return 'ok'
```

So after the second json received and printed everything is freezes and I don't know if is related with post or something else. If is something related with POST, what actually can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community is now better?

Comment: The community robot is right. Sorry, the code here isn't enough to reproduce the problem. It looks like a totally normal request and (partial) post handler, but the error seemingly has to do with qt, and you mention opencv, which wasn't discussed anywhere else in the post. Are you responding to the request from the server anywhere?

Comment: @ggorlen ok give me 5 min